# React and redux usage with async data fetching

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this action

```
export function fetchBranches() {
  return async dispatch => {
    const result = await axios.get('https://localhost:5002/Branches')
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_BRANCHES, payload: result.data.value })
  }
}
```

and such reducer

```
export const branchReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_BRANCHES: {
      return { ...state, branches: action.payload }
    }
    default: return state
  }
}
```

In my component, I'm try to do such thing

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
dispatch(fetchBranches())
const branches = useSelector(state => state.branches.branches)

return <>
  some component that uses branches
</>
```

So my problem is i'm getting infinite number of request trying to fetch (I can see them in redux dev tools).
My page are not getting updated, but if go to other page and then return to one that tries perform this fetch, I'm can see values in store and at the page. So questions are:

1. Where and how should I dispatch actions to fetch some data to render it then?
2. Why I'm getting that much requests and how can I fix it?

UPD:
Thanks a lot for your answers, but I still see behavior that my component rendered before I received data from api. I wanted to try `useState` and set state in `useEffect`, but I can't use `useSelector`. What should I do to re-render component as soon as my data loaded?

UPD2: now my component look like

```
function BranchList() {
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchBranches())
    setIsLoaded(true)
  }, [])

  const branches = useSelector(state => state.branches.branches)
  const headerNames = ["Id", "Name"]

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return <>Loading...</>
  }
  
  return (
    <EditableTable
      data={branches}
      headerNames={headerNames}
      onEditConfirm={(row) => dispatch(updateBranch(row))}
      onDelete={(id) => dispatch(deleteBranch(id))} />
    )
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a full sample of your component? Have you considered the useEffect hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps if you try this:

```
function BranchList() {
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!isLoaded) {
        dispatch(fetchBranches())
            .then(() => setIsLoaded(true))
    }
    
  }, [isLoaded])

  const branches = useSelector(state => state.branches.branches)
  const headerNames = ["Id", "Name"]

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return <>Loading...</>
  }
  
  return (
    <EditableTable
      data={branches}
      headerNames={headerNames}
      onEditConfirm={(row) => dispatch(updateBranch(row))}
      onDelete={(id) => dispatch(deleteBranch(id))} />
    )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was pretty close with it. What's the difference with my code? It's works as I expected because of `.then()` or I missed dependecy for `useEffect`?

Comment: Using isLoaded in your dependency array for useEffect was probably the most significant change

Comment: the .then is keeping the setIsLoaded function from being called until the async dispatch(fetchBranches()) is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Dispatching generally should never be done directly in render, but in a `useEffect` or an event callback.
In your case,

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch()
useEffect(() => { 
  dispatch(fetchBranches());
  }, 
  [dispatch]
)
const branches = useSelector(state => state.branches.branches)
```

Also please note that you are writing a pretty old style of redux here - please read the [official tutorials](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) to learn the recommended "modern" style of redux we are officially recommending. You'll end up writing a lot less code.

Answer (score 1):

You should try putting your dispatch action into an useEffect, so the code will be only executed once like so:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()

React.useEffect(() => {
dispatch(fetchBranches())
}, [])
```

Documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your HTTP request action causes side effects in the component. Every state change causes re-rendering the component. To avoid side effects, you should use useEffect hook in your component.

In your component,

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const onFetchBranches = useCallback(() => dispatch(fetchBranches()), [dispatch]);

const branches = useSelector(state => state.branches.branches)

useEffect(() => {
  onFetchBranches();
}, [onFetchBranches]);

return <>
  some component that uses branches
</>
```

You should check Reactjs documentation to understand useEffect hook better.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Answer (score 1):

`dispatch` an `action` into `useEffect` hook to solve your issue.

Try:

```
useEffect(() => dispatch(fetchBranches()), [])
```